# keybind to scroll down suggestions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I've set up typeahead to return search results. the results are returning correctly, however the expected functionality of being able to press the up and down buttons to cycle through the search results, to autocomplete the text box is not working. I cant figure out why.

```js
var items = [{"Name":"TestAccount", "AccountID":"TestID"},{"Name":"TestAccount2", "AccountID":"TestID2"}]  



var templ = Hogan.compile('<div class="search-result"><a href="/Account/Edit/{{AccountID}}">{{Name}}</a></div>');
        var myTA = $('.js-header-search-box').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        }, {
            name: "Accounts",
            valueKey: "AccountID",
            engine: Hogan,
            templates: {
                empty: [
                  '<div class="empty-message">',
                  'unable to find any items that match the current query',
                  '</div>'
                ].join('\n'),
                suggestion: function (data) { return templ.render(data); }
            },
            source: function (query, process) { process(items);
                }
              
            
        });

        myTA.on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
            var id = datum['AccountID'];
            document.location.href = area + '/Account/Edit' + id + '/';
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/builds/3.0.1/hogan-3.0.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<input autocomplete="off" class="js-header-search-box header-search-box" placeholder="Account name or postcode" type="text" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `displayKey` for that. Something like below

```
displayKey: function(accnt){
  return accnt.Name;
}
```

> **displayKey** – For a given suggestion object, determines the string representation of it. This will be used when setting the value of the input control after a suggestion is selected. Can be either a key string or a function that transforms a suggestion object into a string. Defaults to value.

[Here is the reference](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets)

Here is a ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/9gnj62L0/5/)***